# Get Time on a column disregarding the text

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

in the database, I have columns. - My query is -

```
SELECT Emp_Name, Schedule 
FROM emp_schedule
```

It reurns this resultset:

```
Emp_Name        Schedule

M.S.Cave        10:00 AM - 7:00 PM Semi Flexi
M.S.Cave        10:00 AM - 7:00 PM Semi Flexi
K.V.Boreta      9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Fixed
K.V.Boreta      9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Fixed
R.M.Mendoza     Branch 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM Sunday RD
R.M.Mendoza     Branch 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM Sunday RD
```

But I want to display the "Schedule" column with time only, disregarding the text.

```
Emp_Name        Schedule

M.S.Cave        10:00 AM - 7:00 PM
M.S.Cave        10:00 AM - 7:00 PM
K.V.Boreta      9:00 AM - 6:00 PM
K.V.Boreta      9:00 AM - 6:00 PM
R.M.Mendoza     8:30 AM to 5:30 PM
R.M.Mendoza     8:30 AM to 5:30 PM
```

Is it possible to do that without TRIM, adding columns or editing my table etc?

Comment: Re-design your table. Have separate columns for start and end time.

Comment: hi sir jarlh, thank you for your immediate response. I can't modify my table because I have permission limitations on modifying tables.

Comment: Hmm.. You really want parse string without string functions? Why not `TRIM`?

Comment: Parsing strings is not Sql strong suit. This is something that the presentation layer would handle better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

I used `REVERSE`, `PATINDEX`, `SUBSTRING` to achieve it. Ignore CTE as I just want to use a temp table.

```
;WITH CTE (Emp_Name, Schedule)
AS (
    SELECT 'M.S.Cave', '10:00 AM - 7:00 PM Semi Flexi'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'M.S.Cave', '10:00 AM - 7:00 PM Semi Flexi'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'K.V.Boreta', '9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Fixed'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'K.V.Boreta', '9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Fixed'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'R.M.Mendoza', 'Branch 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM Sunday RD'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'R.M.Mendoza', 'Branch 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM Sunday RD'
    )
, CTE2 AS (
    SELECT *
    , SUBSTRING(Schedule, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Schedule), LEN(Schedule)) SS
    FROM CTE
    )
SELECT *
,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SS), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(SS)) - 3, LEN(SS)))
FROM CTE2
```

And the result will be like

```
+-------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------+
|  Emp_Name   |              Schedule               |              SS               |  (No column name)  |
+-------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------+
| M.S.Cave    | 10:00 AM - 7:00 PM Semi Flexi       | 10:00 AM - 7:00 PM Semi Flexi | 10:00 AM - 7:00 PM |
| M.S.Cave    | 10:00 AM - 7:00 PM Semi Flexi       | 10:00 AM - 7:00 PM Semi Flexi | 10:00 AM - 7:00 PM |
| K.V.Boreta  | 9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Fixed             | 9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Fixed       | 9:00 AM - 6:00 PM  |
| K.V.Boreta  | 9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Fixed             | 9:00 AM - 6:00 PM Fixed       | 9:00 AM - 6:00 PM  |
| R.M.Mendoza | Branch 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM Sunday RD | 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM Sunday RD  | 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM |
| R.M.Mendoza | Branch 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM Sunday RD | 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM Sunday RD  | 8:30 AM to 5:30 PM |
+-------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: really great it gives exact results awesome

Comment: THIS is what exactly I need! Thank you very much sir! You're a blessing! :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried as follows:

```
select Emp_name,
        reverse(SUBSTRING(reverse(Schedule),charindex(' MP ',REVERSE(Schedule)),len(Schedule)))
        ,substring(Schedule,charindex(' AM ',Schedule)-5,charindex(' PM ',Schedule)-charindex(' AM ',Schedule)+8)
        from emp_schedule
```